# What is the ruling on giving orphans inheritance after our death?

Tags: money, children, inheritance, child-adoption

I am aware that Islam encourages looking after the orphans. It also prohibits giving your own lineage in place of their original lineage (through a change in surname).

But what is the ruling related to giving them inheritance after our death?

Comment: Inheritance in form of irth would be illegal, but wasiya would be acceptable

Comment: Could you please explain about it in an answer @Medi1Saif

Comment: @Medi1Saif What is irth? Is wasiya a will?

Comment: @Ahmed irth is the Arabic word for inheritance. And yes a Will is a wasiya

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those people whom can inherit are described and listed in a number of Verses of the Qur'an. Among them you'll find the (bodily) children, (biological) parents. grandparents and wife/husband, (bodily) sisters and brothers!

But adopted children don't count because of the Verses ([33:4-5](http://legacy.quran.com/33/4-5)) which made Adoption (by naming a child with your name) illegal or void! But sponsoring them is allowed!

So inheritance in therm of irth إرث or [ميراث](http://www.almaany.com/ar/dict/ar-en/%D8%A7+%D8%B1%D8%AB/home.php?word=%D9%85%D9%8A%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%AB&lang_name=ar-en&type_word=0&dspl=0) wouldn't be permissible for adopted children!

But as we know wasiya [الوصية](http://www.almaany.com/ar/dict/ar-en/%D8%A7+%D8%B1%D8%AB/home.php?word=%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%88%D8%B5%D9%8A%D8%A9&lang_name=ar-en&type_word=0&dspl=0) or will is always possible as it's [mentioned](http://legacy.quran.com/2/180) and [well](http://legacy.quran.com/5/106)-[ordered](http://legacy.quran.com/4/12) in the Qur'an. And the maximum amount is regulated by the [sunna](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/55/7)!

I only could find fatwas in Arabic on the matter [1](https://islamqa.info/ar/136207) and [2](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/234286) and would like to add an info from the last one, if the inheritance has been divided and the Adopted child had got some of it and there was no last will in his/her favour he/she must give back what he/she got and that would be divided between the heirs!

About orphans sponsoring/adoption see also these two fatwas [1](https://islamqa.info/en/95216) & [2](https://islamqa.info/en/5201).

And Allah knows best!